# How to prove admissibility of a heuristic function

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I know that a heuristic function which never overestimates the real distance to the goal is called admissible. I found a heuristic function does that in practice but i don't know how to give a formal proof. How can i prove that a heuristic function is admissible? For example: Manhattan Distance Heuristic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can formally define the real distance from the goal, then you can simply eliminate a constraint in order to develop an admissible heuristic.

For example: 
The Manhattan distance from point (x1, y1) to point (x2,y2) is equal to |x1-x2|+|y1-y2|.
You can simply eliminate a term to come up with a heuristic. For example h = |x1-x2|. 
To prove that this is an admissible heuristic, you show that |x1-x2| is less than or equal to |x1-x2|+|y1-y2|

...for all x1, x2, y1, y2.

Another admissible heuristic would be the straight line distance, and you can prove that that is always less than the Manhattan distance.

In general, relaxing constraints will lead to admissible heuristics.

If you're working with distances, the straight line distance will always be an admissible heuristic because that will never be an overestimate.

Let me know if this answers your question :)